# Combine multiple csv files with filenames in it as rows on mac terminal

Tags: excel, macos, csv, merge, terminal

I have multiple csv files. I want to combine them in a single file and doing it like this on terminal;

```
"cat *.csv >combined.csv"
```

This works, but I need to add filenames to all of this csv files before merging in order to understand the source of data in the combined version. Now, I have this as combined;

```
a1, a2, a3, a4
b1, a2, a3, a4
```

I want to add filenames as rows to the beginning

```
file1, a1, a2, a3, a4
file2, b1, a2, a3, a4
```

Is there any way to do that on mac terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shell script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

rm combined.csv
for f in *.csv
do
  sed -e "s/^/${f},/" $f >> combined.csv
done
```

It will produce the following in the `combined.csv` file :

```
file1.csv,a1, a2, a3, a4
file2.csv,b1, a2, a3, a4
```